# Merge two tables sql

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.5

This is my data set:
Dataset 1:

```
col2 col3 col4
1      2    3
1      5    6
```

Dataset 2:

```
name2  name3 name4
 a       b     c
 d       e     l
```

I want to merge these two table like this:

```
col2 col3 col4 name2 name3 name4
 1    2     3   a     b     c
 1    5     6   d     e     l
```

I've tried with:

```
select * from table1 join table2 on true;
```

but gives me:

```
col2 col3 col4 name2 name3 name4
1     2    3     a    b      c
1     2    3     d    e      l
```

Which isn't correct. How could i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result should have been four records.

You need a common key to join on, but don't have one.  Here is one method:

```
select t1.col2, t1.col3, t1.col4, t2.name2, t2.name3, t2.name4
from (select t1.*, row_number() over () as seqnum
      from table1 t1
     ) t1 join
     (select t2.*, row_number() over () as seqnum
      from table2 t2
     ) t2
     on t1.seqnum = t2.seqnum;
```

Note that the ordering of the rows (defining the matching) is indeterminate.  If this is important, then include `order by` clauses in the `row_number()` with the appropriate ordering.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, this should work:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.row_number()=table2.row_number();
```

Comment: This is not going to work. You can't use window functions without an `over()` and you can not use them in a join condition like that.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to join in this case.You can just select from both the tables.select * from table1,table2.

Comment: Nope, because i have already tried without success, it gives me the error above explained.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `JOIN` in this case if you want, you can get all columns like this (Because if the same number of columns in both tables):

```
SELECT col2,col3,col4 FROM dataset1
UNION
SELECT name2,name3,name4 FROM dataset2
```

Comment: I can't because they are two different kind of types (integer and string)